# My CSS is overriding a bootstrap table in React

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, react-bootstrap

Inside my react project, inside my `index.css`, I have

```
*{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

to give the entire website a dark theme. However, when I create a table like this with react-bootstrap:

```
<Table striped bordered variant="dark">
    <th></th>
    // etc. 
</Table>
```

my `index.css` file overrides this and keeps the table completely black, instead of having it like how I want it, which can be found [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/#table-inverted).

How would I stop this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: * is a wildcard and basically means every element you make will have "background-color: black". It overrides the bootstrap styles.

Comment: ah ok, thanks @havardsj how would i fix this?

Comment: I would put all my html inside a div with a class called something like container or content. Then change the wildcard selector to that class instead. Basically using anything other than wildcard will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, the * is a wildcard that applies to every element.

In your HTML, the bulk of your code should be within the `<body></body>` tags, and so you should use the following CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```